# What is the cost in time of this function? (Alghoritm analysis)

Tags: algorithm

What is the cost in time in terms of arithmetic operations of this function (in terms of upper bounds)?

```
int foo(int n)
{
    int i;
    if (n <= 3) return 1;
    else if (n > 333) 
    {
        i = n/2;
        return 3 * foo(i) + foo(i) + n * i; 
    }
    else return foo(n - 3) + 9; 
}
```

I tried to analyze it, and these are my thoughts:

1. T(n) is:

   ```
      1                           ; if n ≤ 3
      4T(n/2) + (n2)/2            ; if n > 333       
      T(n-3) + 9                  ; otherwise
   ```
2. So for the second equation, I can say it is `O((n2)/2 logn)`.

Is it correct?

Comment: Should really be on cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't be fooled by all of the operations thrown into the function that are only constant time operations.  Addition, multiplication, comparisons - these are all constant time operations.  The branching recursion is what you need to focus on.

Without changing the complexity at all, I can rearrange the function to this equivalent:

```
int foo(int n)
{
    if (n <= 3) return 1;
    else if (n <= 333) return foo(n - 3) + 9;
    else
    {
        int i = n/2;
        return 3 * foo(i) + foo(i) + n * i; 
    }
}
```

The first two cases essential say "when `n` is less than some fixed constant, there is a bounding constant amount of work left to do."  So the only way we could end up with more than `O(1)` is the last `else` block.

In there, the only non-constant time operation is the two calls to `foo(n/2)`. So we have the recursive relation

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/2) = 2T(n/2)
```

which yields

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) = 4T(n/4) = 8T(n/8) = ... = O(n)
```

So the complexity of `foo(n)` is `O(n)`.

---

WolframAlpha agrees with me:
[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29+%3D+2*T%28n%2F2%29](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29+%3D+2%2aT%28n%2F2%29)

You would have to have a recurrence relation of the form `T(n) = O(n) + 2*T(n/2)` to get `T(n) = O(n log n)`. Again, WolframAlpha agrees:
[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29+%3D+n+%2B+2*T%28n%2F2%29](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29+%3D+n+%2B+2%2aT%28n%2F2%29)

Comment: Curious observation, though - if the `3 * foo(i) + foo(i)` were rewritten as `4 * foo(i)`, which, unless I'm missing something subtle, would be equivalent for any `n` - the complexity becomes `O(log n)`. Since `foo()` doesn't have any discernible side effects, I wonder if any current compilers would consider that as an "optimization"?

Comment: @twalberg Typically when you're doing complexity analysis like this, compilers and possible optimizations are out of the picture.

Comment: I know that, of course... It just caught my eye as a "low-hanging fruit" sort of improvement to the algorithm...